# Best way to do a visit step to a page with a different format (cucumber)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
Scenario: Reading feeds via json
    When I go to the feeds page using json
    Then I should see a json file
    And I should see 3 feeds in the json file
```

However I'm not sure how to get the "When I go to the feeds page using json" to result to feeds_path(:format => "json") in the steps.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that will work flexibly with any format (or lack of):

In your paths.rb file:

```
def path_to(page_name)
    # Split out format if page_name includes ' using '
    # Example: When I go to the accounts page using json
    page_name, format = page_name.split(' using ')
    case page_name

    when /the home\s?page/
      '/'
    when /the new account page/
      #pass format
      new_account_path(:format => format)

    else
      begin
        page_name =~ /the (.*) page/
        path_components = $1.split(/\s+/)
        # Also make sure to pass format to the 'guessed' path
        self.send(path_components.push('path').join('_').to_sym, :format => format)
      rescue Object => e
        raise "Can't find mapping from \"#{page_name}\" to a path.\n" +
          "Now, go and add a mapping in #{__FILE__}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
When %r{^I go to the (\w+) page using (\w+)$} do |page, format|
  path = self.send([page, 'path'].join('_').to_sym, :format => format)
  visit path
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
When /^I go to the feeds page using json$/ do
  visit feeds_path(:format => "json")
end
```

Comment: This doesn't work, comes up with: Ambiguous match of "I go to the feeds page using json"

Comment: You must have a step definition for it already then. What is the body?

Comment: Well, "When I go to (.+)" is defined in web_steps.rb, and we don't want to mess with web_steps.rb

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this in your paths.rb file:

```
  def path_to(page_name)
    case page_name
    when /^the feeds page( using (.*?))?$/
      format, uri = $2, '/feeds'
      format.blank? ? uri : "#{uri}.#{format}"
    end
  end
```

[UPDATED]

Comment: Yeah, but that means I'd have to have two for each path, and that's just not very 'Ruby' ;)

Comment: I updated my answer to only use one path entry to match formatted and non-formatted routes.